# c++ lambda: is it possible to create new lambda by closing open arguments?

Tags: c++, lambda

With EIFFEL agents (https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/Event_Programming_with_Agents#Open_and_Closed_Arguments) one has open and closed arguments. To me this is similar to arguments and captures in lambdas.

What I wonder is whether I can "close/capture" an open argument of a labda to get a new lambda with a different signature with fewer arguments.

Something like this maybe:

```
std::function<void(int, float, string) baseLambda = [](int d, float f, string s){printf("%d%f%s",d,f,s.c_str())};
std::function<void(int,string)> partiallyClosedLambda = baseLambda(?, 1.0f, ?);
partiallyClosedLambda(3,"foo"); // would print "31.0foo"
```

Is there such a mechanism in c++?

of course I could define a new lambda manually

```
std::function<void(int,string)> partiallyClosedLambda = [&baseLambda](int d, string s) { baseLambda(d, 1.0f, s); }
```

But I wonder if there is some syntactic sugar for this?

Comment: Side-note: Don't store it in a `std::function` unless you want it to be needlessly inefficient. Just store it to an `auto` to preserve the raw type.

Comment: @ShadowRanger what kind of inefficiency are you talking exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There is [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), which may be what you are looking for:

```cpp
using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, etc.
auto base = [](int d, float f, std::string s) { /* do stuff */ };
auto partially_closed = std::bind(base, _1, 1.0f, _2);

// now you can do
partially_closed(10, "hello!");
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/410c788caec826c9

Note that storing lambdas in `std::function` is generally not ideal unless you need to (such as in a class), since `std::function` will sometimes need to perform extra allocations (as it's a type-erased polymorphic wrapper). Using `auto` creates a variable of the exact (unnameable) lambda type, which obviously doesn't require any extra allocations.

Comment: yep I think that's what I was looking for. is the exact type of a lambda really unnameable?

Comment: it seems if I do it like this, I cannot pass 'partially_closed' as an argument to a function that takes `std::function<void(int, string)>` as an argument

Comment: That's interesting; I can. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef4e35bfed005313. And yes, lambdas are unnameable; they're some unique closure type, local to the function that calls them.

Comment: @user1282931 Note that the same deal as `auto` vs. `std::function` is with functions; if you're just calling the function, better to make it a template ([like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/321e910ed67e169f), or [ref qualified](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8be002d8690f597)) than taking a `std::function` and all the overhead that implies.  (And in my last comment I meant "creates", not "calls".)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a new lambda that captures the first one. Then you can call the first lambda in your second lambda's body.

```
auto baseLambda = [](int d, float f, string s) { printf("%d%f%s", d, f, s.c_str()); };

auto partiallyClosedLambda = [&baseLambda](int d, string s) { 
    // Call the first lambda. We pass the `d` and `s` parameters we receive as arguments from the second (current) lambda, while the float argument is hard-coded as 1.0
    baseLambda(d, 1.0, s); 
};
partiallyClosedLambda(3, "foo"); // would print "31.0foo"
```